# UserNotFound mongodb error

Tags: mongodb, management, database-user

I know there are lot of articles with the same issue and I explored every other article trying everything and still this error persists.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. use admin.
2. created an admin user with role: dbAdminAnyDatabase
3. use mydb.
4. created an admin user with different name for mydb
5. created a readonly user with: `db.createUser({user: "nameuser", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "read", db: "mydb"}]});`
6. setup a mongod.conf file with:
7. security:
   authorization: enabled

   net:
   port: 12345
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0   #default value is 127.0.0.1
8. then run the command: `sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath ~/data/mongodb --config /etc/mongod.conf`
9. and then on localhost i run the command to check:

   mongo -u nameuser -p password localhost:12345/mydb
10. then the error come as:

    `connecting to: mongodb://localhost:12345/mydb MongoDB server version: 3.6.3 2020-10-04T03:05:37.054+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. : DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20 @(auth):6:1 @(auth):1:2 exception: login failed`
11. and on server side the error looks like this:

    `2020-10-04T02:53:11.835+0530 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60240 #3 (1 connection now open) 2020-10-04T02:53:11.835+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:60240 conn: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.6.3" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "18.04" } } 2020-10-04T02:53:11.836+0530 I ACCESS   [conn3] SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for nameuser on mydb from client 127.0.0.1:60240 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user nameuser@mydb 2020-10-04T02:53:11.837+0530 I NETWORK  [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:60240 (0 connections now open)`

Now please tell me if I can try anything new. I have tried so many articles from stackoverflow but none address the issue. Every resolved issue is the common mistake which I have checked already and I am not doing any of these. Tell me if you have any suggestion to work this out.

Comment: Try running `db.getUsers()` in each database to see which user is where.

Comment: The server says the user doesn't exist.  Are you sure step 5 succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

> --authenticationDatabase admin

parameter...  Because, even you give "use mydb" before creating user...  User is created at the admin -database.

So,

*mongo -u nameuser -p password  --authenticationDatabase admin localhost:12345/mydb*

Comment: I tried this. There was still an error. I tried making owner of same name for that database too. and then try this command  but still there is same error.